# Which stream does "stack smashing detected" message get printed to?

Tags: c, bash, buffer-overflow, stack-smash

Consider the following very basic program, which has appeared in many forms on other questions here.

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char message[8];
    strcpy(message, "Hello, world!");
}
```

On my system, if I put this in a file called `Classic.c`, compile it with no special flags and run it, I get the following output.

```
$ gcc -o Classic Class.c 
$ ./Classic
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./Classic terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Normally, program output goes to `stderr` or `stdout`, so I expected that the following would produce no output.

```
./Classic  2> /dev/null > /dev/null
```

However, the output is exactly the same, so I have three questions to this scenario.

1. What stream is being printed to here?
2. How could I write code that prints to this special stream (without smashing my stack deliberately).
3. How can I redirect the output of this stream?

Note I am running on a Linux system. Specifically, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @user3386109, how would the shell know? Stack smash detection is generally instrumented at the compiler level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's not stderr or stdout, there's only one remaining option: The controlling tty.

You can write to this with your code by opening `/dev/tty`.

Redirecting its output is intentionally very difficult (this is why `/dev/tty` is also used for password prompts). That said, if you really want to do it, `expect` can be used for this purpose, as can [emPTY](http://empty.sourceforge.net/).

---

The easiest approach with `expect` is to use the included helper `unbuffer`, which will effectively redirect this content to stdout:

```
$ sh -c 'echo hello >/dev/tty' >/dev/null 2>&1
hello
$ unbuffer sh -c 'echo hello >/dev/tty' >/dev/null 2>&1
$
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on using `expect` for this purpose?

Comment: I wonder why segmentation faults and float point exceptions could be redirected, but this one cannot?

Comment: @Flyingonion Redirecting a SIGSEGV notice isn't all that easy -- generally, `foo >out 2>err` doesn't work, and you have to use `{ foo; } >out 2>err` so that *the shell that's running it* (and thus printing logs from its signal handler) has its own stderr redirected. Whereas here the message is printed by the libc of the program being run (`foo` in my example), but it's that libc that's trying to grab a TTY handle when it can.

Comment: Well finally I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301711/how-can-a-unix-program-display-output-on-screen-even-when-stdout-and-stderr-are)