# I'm trying to put the int 100 in a variable malloced 1, why doesn't this program crash?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Ok, so I'm screwing around with C trying to break stuff in a somewhat safe manner, like calling `malloc(100000000000000)` and having my computer run out of memory for a microsecond, and I thought, what would happen if I tried to put too much info in a variable, so I did this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int *p;
    p = malloc(1);
    *p = 100;
    printf("%d", *p);
    free(p);
    printf("%d", *p);
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This does two things I didn't expect.

- First, it prints `p` twice. I though `p` would "vanish" after I freed it. (Though on second thought, I may have to let the OS run a while before it vanished.)
- Second, I expected it to crash. I'm putting 100, a 4 byte int in a box that I think is supposed to be 1 byte. Does `malloc(1)` malloc one byte? Or is it more like `malloc(sizeof(int))`? Why does this work? And, assuming the compiler would let me, how would I cause the buffer overflow (is that the right name here?) that I'm trying to cause?

Pertinent computer info:

- OS: Mac OS X 10.10.latest
- compiler: Xcode, so clang/llvm

Comment: I think in both cases it is invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: This will certainly cause you to overwrite 3 bytes of memory that doesn't belong to you. Then, after calling `free` you try and access 4 bytes of memory that don't belong to you. Any of those of those, by itself, will cause you to venture into the realm of undefined behavior. However there's no _requirement_ that the system crash in response.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979965/which-stream-does-stack-smashing-detected-message-get-printed-to) is an example of a buffer overflow, if you wanted that.

Comment: Cool, thanks guys. I see this is a duplicate question, but hey I've learned something. I'll have to try that buffer overflow you linked to @merlin2011. I'm totally new to this stuff. :)

Comment: There's nothing bad about a question being marked a duplicate. Your question has become one more useful pointer to someone looking for the same information.

Comment: Good to know. :) I just ran that buffer overflow code you linked to. The Xcode debugger shows that the OS didn't even try to fit "Hello, World" into the message. It only gets to "W". :)